# trouble overloading << operator, trouble printing vectors of objects

Tags: c++, vector, overloading, codeblocks

Header file:

```
#ifndef CART_H
#define CART_H

#include "Tops.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Cart
{
public:
    Cart();
    void addTop(Tops& top);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const Cart& c);


private:
    vector<Tops> tops;
};

#endif
```

Implementation file:

```
#include "Cart.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

Cart::Cart() { }

void Cart::addTop(Tops &top)
{
    tops.push_back(top);
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &ostr, const Cart &c)
{
    ostr << "TOPS IN CART:\n-------------\n";
    for (auto const top : c.tops) {ostr << top << endl; } // no match for 'operator<<'

    return ostr;
}
```

Problem:  I keep getting a "no match for operator<<" error and I have no idea why, and I also have no idea what it means.  When I google this error, what has caused the error in other people's codes does not apply to mine.

Comment: Missing a `const`. You need `ostream& operator<<(ostream &ostr, const Cart &c)` in the implementation to match the prototype of the `friend` declaration.

Comment: Several other errors as well `(itt*)` -> `(*itt)`, although you should just use a foreach loop: `for (auto top : c.tops) { ostr << top << endl; }`

Comment: By leaving out the `const` in the implementation, that implementation is a totally different function than what you intended.  It is valid, but it isn't the same function.  That's why you didn't get a compiler error.

Comment: Note: to take advantage of @Justin 's suggestion, make sure your compiler has the C++11 or a more recent standard enabled.

Comment: I changed what both of you said (thank you!!) now I'm getting this error: no match for operator<<

Comment: @Justin: you should **not** use *this* for each loop, though! It creates a copy of each object in the vector. That is, it should be `for (auto const& top: c.tops) { ... }` or `for (auto&& top: c.tops) { ... }`.

Comment: `Tops`, `Bottoms`, and `Skirts` must also have an `<<` overload. You haven't posted them, so we don't know if you have already done this.

Comment: Unrelated: `vector<Tops> getTops()const { return tops; }` will return a copy of `tops`. Be sure this is what you want. The same applies for the other getter functions.

Comment: why do they also need an << overload?

Comment: @EmilyLerman Learn to read and interpret your compilers error messages. Fix them one after another. If you need help with a specific one, narrow it down to a [MCVE] that shows the exact error message, and post that here, along with an exact explanation what you don't understand about that error message.

Comment: Sorry, I recently started using Code::Blocks.  I'm a new linux user and visual studios isn't available on linux. I will do this, and update my question.

Comment: Any custom type you manufacture will need a `<<` overload so that `<<` knows how to print them.

Comment: You can overload the same operator more than once in a project?  I'll try that!

Comment: @EmilyLerman _"You can overload the same operator more than once in a project?"_ That doesn't depend on the _project_, but on the function signature: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const TypeA&)` and `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const TypeB&)` are different enough to let the compiler resolve the _"competing"_ function overload defintions.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Yes, good point. I forgot about that when I wrote it. Code reviews are important

Comment: @Dietmar /OT Still in the `std::stream`s since the late 80ies of the last millenium :-D ...

Comment: thank you!!!! that helped a lot. I'm not getting anymore errors, but nothing prints when I try to print my cart, so now I need to figure that out.

Comment: @user0042: well, I still remember how to use streams effectively and get interested in corresponding questions...

Answer (score 0):

In your declaration you have stated that the Cart argument will be const:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const Cart& cart);
```

but your definition does not:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &ostr, Cart &c)
```

They need to match (either both const or both not - both const would be right here) for the friend declaration to be of any use.

Comment: Bunch of competing mistakes at play here. This is but one.